# Using Python with MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I'm trying to use  Python 3 with MS SQL Server Express 2008 R2.
I'm using Visual Studio as an IDE, and trying to use `pymssql`.

In my code I did the following:

```
conn = _mssql.connect(server='GAL-PC\SQLEXPRESS', user='gal', password='pass', \
database='tempdb')
```

I've set the user name and the password using MS SQL Server Management Studio.

All I'm getting is this error:

```
_mssql.MSSQLDriverException: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.
```

Why is my code giving me an error?

Comment: Is GAL-PC your local PC? If yes, thetn try ```r'.\SQLEXPRESS'```.

Comment: I would try `pyodbc`, I was able to connect to SQL Server 2008 via `pyodbc`